# PHP Date Time Function : Expire The content

Tags: php

How to expire the content from the date of added after two days. 
After Getting data from mysql

```
    //looop starts
    {
       $db_Date = $rows['created_Date']; //output 2014-01-10 12:08:56
      /* Now i have to expire the content after 2 days from the added date and time i.e i want to expire by 2014-03-10 12:08:56*/
//    I tried like this
        $date = new DateTime($rows['created_Date'];);
        $now = new DateTime();  

        if($date < $now) {
            echo 'date is in the past';
        } // this is not working as 

       <div>My Content</div>
    }
```

Comment: Do it from your query instead: `SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 123 AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method.

```
 {
       $db_Date = $rows['created_Date']; //output 2014-01-10 12:08:56
      /* Now i have to expire the content after 2 days from the added date and time i.e i want to expire by 2014-03-10 12:08:56*/
//    I tried like this
        $date = new DateTime($rows['created_Date']);
        $date = $date->modify('+2 days');

        $now = new DateTime();  

        if($date < $now) {
            echo 'date is in the past';
        } // this is not working as 

       <div>My Content</div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($rows['created_Date']);
$date->add(new DateTimeInterval('P2D'));
```

**or** you can use [`DateTime::modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php):

```
$date = new DateTime($rows['created_Date']);
$date->modify('+2 days');
```

**or** (to complete this answer and taking h2ooooooo's answer into account) you could do it directly in SQL:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE id = 123 AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```